Is there any way to manually do nrwl/nx migrations?
I'm trying to upgrade an old nx repo with one Angular app and two Ionic Angular apps, plus firebase functions and about 125 libraries.
I've run npx nx migrate 13.1.4 and get a successful result:

markflegg@Marks-Macbook-Pro-2023 bm-applications % npx nx migrate
13.1.4 @nrwl/tao has been deprecated and will not be published in Nx 17. Please update your global install of nx: https://nx.dev/more-concepts/global-nx Fetching meta data about
packages. It may take a few minutes. Fetching @nrwl/workspace@13.1.4
Fetching @nrwl/jest@13.1.4 Fetching @nrwl/cypress@13.1.4 Fetching
@nrwl/node@13.1.4 Fetching @nrwl/angular@13.1.4 Fetching
@nrwl/storybook@13.1.4
NX   The migrate command has run successfully.

package.json has been updated.
migrations.json has been generated.

NX   Connect to Nx Cloud
Nx Cloud is a first-party CI companion for Nx projects. It improves
critical aspects of CI:

Speed: 30% - 70% faster CI
Cost: 40% - 75% reduction in CI costs
Reliability: by automatically identifying flaky tasks and re-running them

✔ Would you like remote caching to make your build faster? · skip
NX   Next steps:

Make sure package.json changes make sense and then run 'yarn',
Run 'yarn nx migrate --run-migrations'
To learn more go to https://nx.dev/features/automate-updating-dependencies


So far, so good! I run yarn and everything updates without errors:

[1/5]   Validating package.json... [2/5]   Resolving packages...
warning @nrwl/angular > @nrwl/linter > eslint >
@humanwhocodes/config-array@0.5.0: Use @eslint/config-array instead
warning @nrwl/angular > @nrwl/linter > eslint >
@humanwhocodes/config-array > @humanwhocodes/object-schema@1.2.1: Use
@eslint/object-schema instead [3/5]   Fetching packages... warning
chart.js@4.4.1: The engine "pnpm" appears to be invalid. [4/5] 
Linking dependencies... warning " >
@angular/flex-layout@11.0.0-beta.33" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/cdk@^11.0.0". warning " > @angular/localize@11.2.14" has
incorrect peer dependency "@angular/compiler@11.2.14". warning " >
@angular/localize@11.2.14" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/compiler-cli@11.2.14". warning " > @capacitor/camera@6.0.1"
has incorrect peer dependency "@capacitor/core@^6.0.0". warning " >
@ionic/angular@6.5.1-dev.11674603407.1bf3d493" has incorrect peer
dependency "rxjs@>=6.6.0". warning " > @nxtend/capacitor@11.1.1" has
incorrect peer dependency "@nrwl/workspace@^11.0.19". warning " >
@nxtend/ionic-angular@11.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency
"@nrwl/angular@^11.0.19". warning " >
@transistorsoft/capacitor-background-fetch@5.1.1" has incorrect peer
dependency "@capacitor/core@^5.0.0". warning " >
@transistorsoft/capacitor-background-geolocation@5.2.4" has incorrect
peer dependency "@capacitor/core@^5.0.0". warning " >
angular-email-editor@0.9.0" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/common@^7.0.0". warning " > angular-email-editor@0.9.0" has
incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^7.0.0". warning " >
angular-instantsearch@3.0.0-beta.5" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/common@>=5.0.0 <9.0.0". warning " >
angular-instantsearch@3.0.0-beta.5" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/core@>=5.0.0 <9.0.0". warning " >
angular-instantsearch@3.0.0-beta.5" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/platform-browser@>=5.0.0 <9.0.0". warning " >
angular-instantsearch@3.0.0-beta.5" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@>=5.0.0 <9.0.0". warning " >
bootstrap@5.3.2" has unmet peer dependency "@popperjs/core@^2.11.8".
warning " > capacitor-firebase-auth@3.1.2-rc.3" has incorrect peer
dependency "rxjs@~6.6.7". warning "firebase-admin >
@firebase/database-compat > @firebase/database >
@firebase/auth-interop-types@0.1.7" has unmet peer dependency
"@firebase/app-types@0.x". warning " > firebase-functions@5.0.1" has
incorrect peer dependency "firebase-admin@^11.10.0 || ^12.0.0".
warning " > ngx-file-drop@13.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/common@>=13.0.0". warning " > ngx-file-drop@13.0.0" has
incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@>=13.0.0". warning " >
ngx-multiple-dates@13.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/cdk@^13.1.3". warning " > ngx-multiple-dates@13.1.0" has
incorrect peer dependency "@angular/common@^13.1.3". warning " >
ngx-multiple-dates@13.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/core@^13.1.3". warning " > ngx-multiple-dates@13.1.0" has
incorrect peer dependency "@angular/forms@^13.1.3". warning " >
ngx-multiple-dates@13.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/material@^13.1.3". warning " > ngx-multiple-dates@13.1.0"
has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^7.5.2". warning " >
ngx-pinch-zoom@2.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/common@^11.1.2". warning " > ngx-pinch-zoom@2.6.2" has
incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^11.1.2". warning
"@nrwl/angular > @nrwl/cypress > @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.17.1"
has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.1". warning "@nrwl/angular

@nrwl/cypress > @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@^7.0.0". warning "@nrwl/angular >
@nrwl/cypress > @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.17.1" has unmet peer
dependency "babel-loader@^8.0.2 || ^9". warning " >
@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx@13.1.4" has incorrect peer dependency
"@typescript-eslint/parser@~4.33.0". warning " >
@storybook/addon-essentials@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency
"@babel/core@^7.9.6". warning " > @storybook/addon-essentials@6.3.13"
has unmet peer dependency "babel-loader@^8.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-measure@2.0.0" has
unmet peer dependency "@storybook/components@^6.3.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-measure@2.0.0" has
unmet peer dependency "@storybook/core-events@^6.3.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-measure@2.0.0" has
unmet peer dependency "@storybook/theming@^6.3.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addons@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addons@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/api@6.3.13" has unmet peer
dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/api@6.3.13" has unmet peer
dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > storybook-addon-outline@1.4.2" has
unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > storybook-addon-outline@1.4.2" has
unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/builder-webpack5 > @storybook/client-api@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/builder-webpack5 > @storybook/client-api@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/builder-webpack5 > @storybook/components@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/builder-webpack5 > @storybook/components@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/builder-webpack5 > @storybook/theming@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/builder-webpack5 > @storybook/theming@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-actions >
react-inspector@5.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.4 ||
^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs
@mdx-js/react@1.6.22" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs
@storybook/builder-webpack4@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-docs > @storybook/builder-webpack4@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs >
@storybook/core@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 ||
^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs
@storybook/core@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-docs > @storybook/source-loader@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs >
@storybook/source-loader@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency
"react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-docs > react-element-to-jsx-string@14.3.4" has unmet
peer dependency "react@^0.14.8 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.1".
warning "@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs >
react-element-to-jsx-string@14.3.4" has unmet peer dependency
"react-dom@^0.14.8 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.1". warning
"@storybook/builder-webpack5 > @storybook/router@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/builder-webpack5 > @storybook/router@6.3.13" has unmet
peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/api > @reach/router@1.3.4"
has unmet peer dependency "react@15.x || 16.x ||
16.4.0-alpha.0911da3". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/api > @reach/router@1.3.4" has unmet peer dependency
"react-dom@15.x || 16.x || 16.4.0-alpha.0911da3". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-actions >
@storybook/components > markdown-to-jsx@7.3.2" has unmet peer
dependency "react@>= 0.14.0". warning "@storybook/addon-knobs >
react-colorful@5.6.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=16.8.0".
warning "@storybook/addon-knobs > react-colorful@5.6.1" has unmet peer
dependency "react-dom@>=16.8.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials
@storybook/addon-actions > @storybook/components > react-popper-tooltip@3.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.6.0
|| ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-actions > @storybook/components >
react-popper-tooltip@3.1.1" has unmet peer dependency
"react-dom@^16.6.0 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-actions > @storybook/components >
react-syntax-highlighter@13.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=
0.14.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-actions > @storybook/components >
react-textarea-autosize@8.5.3" has unmet peer dependency
"react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-knobs
react-select > @emotion/core@10.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=16.3.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-actions > @storybook/theming >
@emotion/styled@10.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=16.3.0".
warning "@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-actions >
@storybook/theming > emotion-theming@10.3.0" has unmet peer dependency
"react@>=16.3.0". warning "@storybook/builder-webpack5 >
@storybook/core-common@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency
"react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/builder-webpack5 >
@storybook/core-common@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency
"react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/manager-webpack5 >
@storybook/ui@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 ||
^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/manager-webpack5 > @storybook/ui@6.3.13"
has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/manager-webpack5 > @storybook/core-client@6.3.13" has
unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/manager-webpack5 > @storybook/core-client@6.3.13" has
unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs > @storybook/core
@storybook/core-server@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-docs > @storybook/core >
@storybook/core-server@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency
"react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/api > @reach/router > create-react-context@0.3.0" has unmet
peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-actions >
@storybook/components > react-popper-tooltip > react-popper@2.3.0" has
unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17 || ^18". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-actions >
@storybook/components > react-popper-tooltip > react-popper@2.3.0" has
unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17 || ^18". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-actions >
@storybook/components > react-textarea-autosize >
use-composed-ref@1.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 ||
^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-actions > @storybook/components >
react-textarea-autosize > use-latest@1.2.1" has unmet peer dependency
"react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-actions >
@storybook/theming > @emotion/styled > @emotion/styled-base@10.3.0"
has unmet peer dependency "react@>=16.3.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs >
@storybook/builder-webpack4 > @storybook/ui > downshift@6.1.12" has
unmet peer dependency "react@>=16.12.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs >
@storybook/builder-webpack4 > @storybook/ui > markdown-to-jsx@6.11.4"
has unmet peer dependency "react@>= 0.14.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs >
@storybook/builder-webpack4 > @storybook/ui > react-draggable@4.4.6"
has unmet peer dependency "react@>= 16.3.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs >
@storybook/builder-webpack4 > @storybook/ui > react-draggable@4.4.6"
has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>= 16.3.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/addon-docs >
@storybook/builder-webpack4 > @storybook/ui >
react-helmet-async@1.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.6.0 ||
^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-docs > @storybook/builder-webpack4 > @storybook/ui >
react-helmet-async@1.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.6.0
|| ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-docs > @storybook/core > @storybook/core-server >
@storybook/manager-webpack4@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency
"react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-docs > @storybook/core > @storybook/core-server >
@storybook/manager-webpack4@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency
"react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-essentials >
@storybook/addon-actions > @storybook/components >
react-textarea-autosize > use-latest >
use-isomorphic-layout-effect@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency
"react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0". warning " >
@storybook/addon-knobs@6.3.1" has unmet peer dependency
"@storybook/addons@^6.3.0". warning " > @storybook/addon-knobs@6.3.1"
has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/api@^6.3.0". warning " >
@storybook/addon-knobs@6.3.1" has unmet peer dependency
"@storybook/components@^6.3.0". warning " >
@storybook/addon-knobs@6.3.1" has unmet peer dependency
"@storybook/core-events@^6.3.0". warning " >
@storybook/addon-knobs@6.3.1" has unmet peer dependency
"@storybook/theming@^6.3.0". warning "@storybook/addon-knobs >
react-select@3.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 ||
^17.0.0". warning "@storybook/addon-knobs > react-select@3.2.0" has
unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-knobs > react-select > react-input-autosize@3.0.0"
has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.3.0 || ^17.0.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-knobs > react-select > react-transition-group@4.4.5"
has unmet peer dependency "react@>=16.6.0". warning
"@storybook/addon-knobs > react-select > react-transition-group@4.4.5"
has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.6.0". warning " >
@storybook/angular@6.5.16" has unmet peer dependency
"@angular-devkit/architect@>=0.8.9". warning " >
@storybook/angular@6.5.16" has unmet peer dependency
"@angular-devkit/core@^0.6.1 || >=7.0.0". warning " >
@storybook/angular@6.5.16" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".
warning " > @storybook/builder-webpack5@6.3.13" has unmet peer
dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning " >
@storybook/builder-webpack5@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency
"react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning " >
@storybook/manager-webpack5@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency
"react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning " >
@storybook/manager-webpack5@6.3.13" has unmet peer dependency
"react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0". warning " > babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0"
has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0". warning " >
karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0" has incorrect peer dependency
"jasmine-core@>=3.8". warning Workspaces can only be enabled in
private projects. [5/5]   Building fresh packages... success Saved
lockfile. warning "@nrwl/cli" is already in "devDependencies". Please
remove existing entry first before adding it to "dependencies".
warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects. success
Saved 11 new dependencies. info Direct dependencies ├─
@nrwl/angular@13.1.4 ├─ @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx@13.1.4 ├─
@nrwl/node@13.1.4 └─ ng-packagr@12.2.7 info All dependencies ├─
@cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.17.1 ├─ @eslint/eslintrc@0.4.3 ├─
@humanwhocodes/config-array@0.5.0 ├─
@humanwhocodes/object-schema@1.2.1 ├─ @nrwl/angular@13.1.4 ├─
@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx@13.1.4 ├─ @nrwl/node@13.1.4 ├─
acorn-import-attributes@1.9.5 ├─ lodash.merge@4.6.2 ├─
ng-packagr@12.2.7 └─ nx@13.1.4 ✨  Done in 13.34s.
markflegg@Marks-Macbook-Pro-2023 bm-applications % yarn yarn install
v1.22.22 [1/5]   Validating package.json... [2/5]   Resolving
packages... success Already up-to-date. ✨  Done in 0.25s.
markflegg@Marks-Macbook-Pro-2023 bm-applications % npx nx migrate
--run-migrations --create-commits @nrwl/tao has been deprecated and will not be published in Nx 17. Please update your global install of
nx: https://nx.dev/more-concepts/global-nx

NX   Running 'yarn' to make sure necessary packages are installed
yarn install v1.22.22 [1/5]   Validating package.json... [2/5] 
Resolving packages... success Already up-to-date. ✨  Done in 0.25s.
yarn run v1.22.22 $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits
$ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate
--run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate
--run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate
--run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate
--run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits $ yarn nx migrate --run-migrations --create-commits

These lines continue, about one new line per second, infinitely (as far as I can tell). Eventually the system starts to bog down, as it seems to be spawning node processes with these lines.
I have tried everything I can think of to get this working, and am stumped.
I'm wondering if there's a way to manually do each of the migrations in migrations.json... or is there something I need to install or remove to get this unstuck??
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!
